# Change Administrative theme

Tags: theming

I have changed my Administrative Theme to a theme I don't like and now I cannot change it back. There is a drop down to change, but no save configuration option anymore.

Comment: A little context of what theme you changed to what would help here. Maybe a screenshot (or) page source ? Give us something to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it back with drush:

```
drush vset admin_theme seven
```

Or PHP:

```
variable_set('admin_theme', 'seven');
```

Or if you're in a real bind, via the settings.php file temporarily:

```
$conf['admin_theme'] = 'seven';
```

Replace "seven" with the machine name of the theme you want to use for the admin pages.